# How to use @seed in hypothesis?

Tags: python, seed, python-hypothesis

I'm trying to use `@seed` here: https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducing.html#reproducing-a-test-run-with-seed

But when I include it before `@given`, I get the error
`NameError: name 'seed' is not defined` at runtime.

My python script imports `hypothesis`. Should I be importing something else to get the `@seed` feature working?

Comment: Could you add your code please? How are you importing `hypothesis`? With `import hypothesis` or `from hypothesis import given`?

Comment: @DMalan Sorry, it's a private repository, and I don't think I can share it publicly. Previously, it was just `from hypothesis import given` and I added `import hypothesis` as well, but it didn't solve the "seed is not defined" issue. Note hypothesis testing DOES work when I don't use the `@seed`.

Comment: @DMalan Maybe I'm not using @seed properly? I just added the line `@seed(0)` above the `@given(...)` line. That's supposed to be how it works right? That's what I see on the website

Comment: @DMalan I figured it out. I need to add `from hypothesis.core import seed`

Answer (score 0):

As you note in a comment, you need to `from hypothesis import seed` before you can use `@seed` without qualification.

This is not specific to Hypothesis, it's just how imports work in Python generally :-)